# Присвоение id пользователя в связанной таблице

Tags: база-данных, yii2, связывание-данных

Есть две таблицы: users и posts. Связь через id пользователя и userId поста.Связь один ко многим. У одного пользователя много постов. Как через форму в yii2(или может быть как-то ещё) сделать так,чтобы при создании поста в админке автоматически присваивался id пользователя,который его создаёт?

Answer (score 0):

Чтоб прям совсем на автомате, то надо добавить в таблицу `posts` два поля `created_by` и `updated_by`, а в классе модели добавить бихевиор, как ниже. Также не забыть указать эти поля в рулсах у модели

```
use yii\behaviors\BlameableBehavior;

public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        BlameableBehavior::class,
    ];
}
```

В методе `rules()`

```
[['created_by'], 'safe'],
```

Если уже есть поля для определения автора и последнего, кто изменял запись, то их можно указать в свойствах бихевиора.

```
return [
    [
        'class' => BlameableBehavior::class,
        'createdByAttribute' => 'user_id',
        'updatedByAttribute' => 'updater_id',
    ],
];
```

Comment: А вот это разве не оно? public function getAuthAssignments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(AuthAssignmentModel::className(), ['item_name' => 'name']);
    }

Comment: Я понятия не имею, что это. На реляцию похоже, если hasMany

Answer (score 0):

Аня, можешь как fedornabilkin через поведение сделать, либо в модели можешь метод переопределить:

```js
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function beforeSave($insert): bool
    {
        if ($this->isNewRecord) {
            $this->created_by = Yii::$app->user->identity->getId();
        }

        return parent::beforeSave($insert);
    }
```